# Can not find element using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, xpath

There is a web element:

```
<select id="sel" onchange="refresh('sel')">
  <option value="1"> A</option>
  <option value="2"> B</option>
</select>
```

Because it has `onchange`, I can not select the option. My code is like this:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("sel"))).selectByValue("1");
```

But it can not work. Is it possible to make it to work?

Comment: If you can,please answer my question in Java, thanks very much

Comment: added Java tag to help with that :P

Comment: Well what does the `onchange` event do?

Comment: the onchange event is probably refresh the select filter

Comment: whats the exception thrown?

Comment: to  niharika_neo: no exception throw , because the element can be found, but can not select..

Comment: to Ameoo, Xpath seems no help,too. I think may be onchange event need some other way to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Use the xpath instead of using id. Because as per the code, it will refresh the screen once u select the value. Try using xpath and after the xpath give some wait period for refreshing.

Comment: Hi , I use xpath but still can't select. . .

Comment: how can I deal with the onchange event?

Comment: Whats happening after the onchange event is triggered? Is the value retains or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'll try to do:(C#)

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(XPATH_FOR_OPTION));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].fireEvent('onclick');", element);
```