# webdriver, can you help to get the options using java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

[this is my old question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685905/can-not-find-element-using-webdriver)

I think putting up a website may be of help.
This is our website: https://sort.symantec.com/patch/finder
Can you help to get one option selected? 
like: "AIX" in "platform"

I still can not figure it out. Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not find element using webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685905/can-not-find-element-using-webdriver) (It really does not make sense to open the same question within a day of each other.)

Answer (score 2):

My approach in these cases is:

1. Install [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/plugins.jsp)
2. Record the testcase in Selenium IDE
3. Select Options -> Options... in the Selenium IDE
4. Select desired language format
5. Click "Source"
6. Use the code as first draft

Comment: Does webdriver has IDE, too? my ide is 1.0, and it only can get code for selenium1.0

Comment: Yes, I can see Webdriver /Junit 4 format in my Selenium IDE version 1.10.0 - try updating the plugin

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.Id("sel_platform"));
Select dropDown = new Select(element);
value = "AIX";
dropDown.selectByValue(value);
```

My Java is a little off, so you may need to change it, but the idea is you need the `Select` class, it will do what you are after.

Looking at the Javascript of your `onchange` problem (shown in your older thread), it is simply changing the values of each dropdown showing only the versions of that software. For instance, if I click `Veritas Cluster Server` in the first dropdown, the `refresh_filters` function is fired by the `onchange` event, ensuring that the platforms shown are the platforms `Veritas Cluster Server` is *supported* on, and likewise with what versions it has.

This **should not** stop you from using the methods above, or anything else shown in your previous old product.

**Do not work against the application** - the whole point of this is to work as the user would. A user would select a product, then their platform, then their version - **not** the way you are doing it. (Which appears to be selecting the platform first).

So in conclusion: **select the product**, then **select the platform**, then **select the version**.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but not work, although select the product first, can you select the option? my ff version is 17.0.1

Comment: @Tingting, how does it not work? What does it do? Does it select nothing? Does it throw an error? Works fine for me, using that page, in FF 17 *and* Chrome v24 *and* IE9.

Comment: Hi Arran, I use your code, just a little change : selectByValue       WebElement m = driver.findElement(By.id("sel_platform"));
Select n = new Select(m);
String v = "AIX";
n.selectByVisibleText(v);

Comment: the result is nothing happened, no error no exception, but option can not selected...